# How to solve the following Laplace equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Im struggling to find a solution for the following problem

$$ \begin{cases}
\varDelta u\left(x,y\right)=0 & \forall\left(x,y\right)\in\left(0,2\right)\times\left(0,2\right)\\
u\left(x,0\right)=\sin\left(\pi x\right) & \forall x\in[0,2]\\
u\left(x,2\right)=\sin\left(3\pi x\right) & \forall x\in[0,2]\\
u\left(0,y\right)=0 & \forall y\in[0,2]\\
u\left(2,y\right)=\min\left\{ y,\left(2-y\right)\right\}  & \forall y\in[0,2]
\end{cases} $$

I'll explain what I have tried.

I dont know to solve this equation as is. What I do know is to solve Laplace equation's with homogenous boudary conditions. So I tried to find a function $ w(x,y) $ such that either $$ \begin{cases}
u\left(x,0\right)-w\left(x,0\right)=0, & \forall x\in[0,2]\\
u\left(x,2\right)-w\left(x,2\right)=0 & \forall x\in[0,2]
\end{cases} $$

Or $$ \begin{cases}
u\left(0,y\right)-w\left(0,y\right)=0, & \forall y\in[0,2]\\
u\left(2,y\right)-w\left(2,y\right)=0 & \forall y\in[0,2]
\end{cases} $$

So I defined $ w\left(x,y\right)=\sin\left(\pi x+\pi xy\right) $, and then I defined

$ v\left(x,y\right)=u\left(x,y\right)-w\left(x,y\right) $

So that $$  \begin{cases}
\varDelta v\left(x,y\right)=\left(\left(\pi+\pi y\right)^{2}+\left(\pi x\right)^{2}\right)\sin\left(\pi x+\pi xy\right) & \left(x,y\right)\in\left(0,2\right)\times\left(0,2\right)\\
v\left(x,0\right)=0 & \forall x\in[0,2]\\
v\left(x,2\right)=0 & \forall x\in[0,2]\\
v\left(0,y\right)=0 & \forall y\in[0,2]\\
v\left(2,y\right)=\min\left(y,\left(2-y\right)\right)-\sin\left(\pi x+\pi xy\right) & \forall y\in[0,2]
\end{cases}$$

I do know how to solve this equation, but it requires too much work and Im sure there is a simpler solution.

I'll show my way to solve this equatoin:

I'll use the Fourier series by the orthogonal system $ \left\{ \sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty} $ (which consists of eigenfunctions of the Laplace eigenvalue equation in the $ y $ direction in the homogenous case)

And I'll write each function as its generlized Fourier series:

$ \begin{cases}
v\left(x,y\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_{n}\left(x\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)\\
\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial x^{2}}\left(x,y\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}X_{n}\left(x\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)\\
\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial y^{2}}\left(x,y\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Z_{n}\left(x\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)\\
\left(\left(\pi+\pi y\right)^{2}+\left(\pi x\right)^{2}\right)\sin\left(\pi x+\pi xy\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)\\
\min\left(y,\left(2-y\right)\right)-\sin\left(\pi+\pi xy\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)
\end{cases} $

One can check that the following holds:

$ \begin{cases}
X_{n}=\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}Y_{n}\left(x\right)\\
Z_{n}=-\frac{\pi^{2}n^{2}}{4}Y_{n}\left(x\right)\\
\\
\end{cases} $

So we get $$ \begin{cases}
v\left(x,y\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_{n}\left(x\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)\\
\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial x^{2}}\left(x,y\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}Y_{n}\left(x\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)\\
\frac{\partial^{2}v}{\partial y^{2}}\left(x,y\right)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\pi^{2}n^{2}}{4}Y_{n}\left(x\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)\\
\left(\left(\pi+\pi y\right)^{2}+\left(\pi x\right)^{2}\right)\sin\left(\pi x+\pi xy\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)\\
\min\left(y,\left(2-y\right)\right)-\sin\left(\pi+\pi xy\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)
\end{cases} $$

And we now how to calculate $ A_n $ and $ C_n $ because its gonna be the inner product in $L^2 $  between $\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right) $ and the compatible function.

So if we'll insert each series into Laplace equation, and use the uniquness of the coefficients, we'll get an ordinary differential equation

$ \frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}Y_{n}\left(x\right)-\frac{\pi^{2}n^{2}}{4}Y_{n}\left(x\right)=A_{n} $

And we have intial condition because $$ 0=v\left(0,y\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_{n}\left(0\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)\to Y_{n}\left(0\right)=0 $$

And $ v\left(2,y\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_{n}\left(2\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{2}y\right)\to Y_{n}\left(2\right)=A_{n} $

So if I'll work hard enough and calculate all those integrals, I will get a solution for $Y_n $ and therefore also for $ v(x,y) $ and then for $ u(x,y) $.

But Im looking for much simple way.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I tried to define $ w\left(x,y\right)=\frac{\left(2-y\right)}{2}\sin\left(\pi x\right)+\frac{y}{2}\sin\left(3\pi x\right) $

And solve as I explained, but it also lead me to an endless algebra calculations.